# Auto positioning div as one scrolls the page down/up

Tags: css, html

Please see this [UI sketch](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/4710/screenshotxd.png) image, I have this div in sidebar (black box) on a certain site and as I scroll down or scroll up, I don't want it to hide...I want it to move itself down as I scroll down and move itself up as I scroll back up so that it never hides out. Can you recommend me some jQuery that can get this done? or something else. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for this please; it's pure CSS.

```
#MyDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Adjust the exact position to your liking by adjusting `top` and `left`. Maybe you want it centered vertically like in the image (if the sketch is accurate in that aspect), in which case you have to deal with all the fun [tricks necessary for vertical centering](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html); hopefully in your case something like this would work:

```
#MyDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; /* This places the _top_ of the div in the middle of the page. */
    left: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px; /* This moves the div upward by half of its height,
                           thus aligning the middle of the div with the middle
                           of the page. */
}
```

Comment: Yup. jQuery != instant solution.

Comment: Actually I don't want the div to be adjusted in the middle of the page exactly and only when the page loads. I want it to be adjusted in real time as the user scrolls down to reveal more content, the div also keeps scrolling down to stay visible to the user. I hope you get it now

Comment: Yes, that is why we are using `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

Comment: I just found a jQuery plugin that can do it: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jStickyScroll.

Thanks Domenic for explaining the CSS.

Comment: Don't use jQuery for this; it will make your page slow :(.